# A classification problem of the subsets in $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ which behave like odd numbers when considered in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Classify all the subsets $S$ of the set of cartesian product of integers $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that: If $x$ is in $S$ then $-x$ also in $S$; if $x$ and $y$ are in $S$, then $x+ y$ is in complement of $S$ and finally if $x$ is in $S$ and $y$ is in the complement of $S$ then $x+y$ is in S.

Comment: Addition is componentwise?

Comment: @Nishant yes it is

Comment: Empty set included?

Comment: @LeeNeverGup The question is about classifying. Everything which satisfies those all included. Yes of course empty set is a member.

Comment: Look at the two points (1,0) and (0,1).  What if you have one but not the other in S? What if you have both? Neither?

Comment: the subset whose 1st component is odd number, is a member. Same true for the 2nd component. Are there others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subsets $S \subseteq \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ that suffice

1. $x \in S \Rightarrow -x \in S$
2. $x,y \in S \Rightarrow x+y \not \in S$
3. $x \in S, y \not \in S \Rightarrow x+y \in S$.

are exactly the empty set and the complements of the subgroups of index $2$ in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$:

Let $S$ suffice all properties. We show that the complement $A:=S^c$ is an additive subgroup:

- suppose $0 \in S$, then $0 = 0+0 \not \in S$ by **2**, a contradiction. So $0 \in A$.
- Let $x \in A$. Suppose $-x \in S$, then $x = -(-x) \in S$ by **1**, a  contradiction. Thus $-x \in A$.
- Let $x,y \in A$. Then $x= (x+y)+(-y) \in A$ and as $-y \in A$ we conclude by **3** that $x+y \in A$.

Furthermore by **2** we know that in the quotient $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /S^c$, which is well-defined as $S^c$ is a group, the sum of two non-trivial elements is $0$. As this implies that any two non-trivial elements are inverse to each other and inverses are uniquely determined, we have $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /S^c = \Bbb Z /2 \Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z /S^c = 0$, so $S^c$ is of index $1$ or $2$.

On the other hand, any complement of a subgroup of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ suffices **1** and **3** and if its index is $1$ or $2$, the second condition holds as well.

Comment: What's wrong with $\{(a,b)\mid a+b\text{ is odd}\}$?

Comment: Hm... the complement is a group, so I probably made an error in the last part... Thank you!

Comment: @HenningMakholm right, so we only know that for non-trivial $S$ the index of $S^c$ is $2$. If anyone finds a characterization of those subgroups, feel free to use any of the above results to give a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we define "$+$" on $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ as $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ then $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z,+)$ is a group.

**Lemma 1:** If S satisfy conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ then $S^c$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. (@benh already proved this.)

So you have to look in complements of subgroups of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ that satisfy the $(2^{nd})$ condition.

**Lemma 2:** If $m\Bbb Z \times n\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ that its complement satisfies the second condition then its index in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is $1$ or $2$. (@benh already proved this.)

**Lemma 3:** For any $m,n\in\Bbb N$, the function $f:\Bbb Z_{mn}\rightarrow\frac{{\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z}}{{m\Bbb Z \times n\Bbb Z}}$, defined by $f(x)=x+m\Bbb Z \times n\Bbb Z$. is an isomorphism, so
$$[\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z:m\Bbb Z \times n\Bbb Z]=mn.$$

**Theorem:** The only subsets $S$ of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ that satisfy those three conditions are,
$$(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z)^c=\emptyset,(2\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z)^c,(\Bbb Z \times 2\Bbb Z)^c.$$

---

It seems that @Nate in his/her comment mentioned the answer very shortly!

Answer (score 1):

We need three rules:

- $x\in S \implies -x\in S$
- $x\in S,y\in S \implies x+y\notin S$
- $x\in S, y\notin S \implies x+y\in S$

We can infer some attributes, like:

- $0 \notin S$, since both $x$ and $-x$ in $S$ and $0=x+(-x)$. Also, otherwise $0+y$ and $y$ must be in diffferent groups.
- $x\in S \implies x+x=2x\notin S$
- $x\in S \implies x+2x=3x \in S$
- In general, for any integer $n$, $2nx\in S$ and $(2n+1)x\notin S$.
- finally, if you have $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ all in S, $\sum a_ix_i$ is in S iff $\sum a_i$ is odd.

So any subset S such that is defined by a "basis" $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$. The basis need to be lineary independent over $Z$, or it will be contradiction or not minimal. Infinite basis is also possible.

Proof that all 3 axioms holds:

- $x\in S \implies x=\sum a_i*x_i, \sum a_i \space odd \implies -x=\sum (-a_i)*x_i, \sum (-a_i) \space odd \implies-x\in S$
- $x\in S,y\in S \\
  \implies x=\sum a_i*x_i, \sum a_i \space odd, y=\sum b_i*x_i, \sum b_i \space odd \\
  \implies x+y=\sum(a_i+b_i)x_i, \sum(a_i+b_i)=(\sum a_i+\sum b_i) \space even\\
  \implies x+y\notin S$
- similar proof for the third property.